# Append something at the end of an echo command in batch

Tags: batch-file, append, echo

I want to append an extra bit of text behind an already executed echo command. For example "Done" or "Failed" based on if something went well or not.

I am trying to create a batch file that checks if a file exists, then proceeds to the next step. I admit I'm not as good with batch, My current solution is, using goto statements, printing a new line with either if it went well or not.

Current solution:

```
@echo off
cls
echo Checking if the file is present...

if exist "file" goto :Next
color 4
echo File not found!
pause
exit

:Next
color a
echo Done.
:: Rest of the script continues here.
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
@echo off
cls
echo Checking if the file is present...

if exist "file" goto :Next
:: Here it should append "File not found!" at the end of the previous echo
pause
exit

:Next
:: Here it should append "Done." at the end of the previous echo

:: Rest of the script continues here.
```

The expected result would in simple terms allow something at the end of an a line I previously output via echo, to be appended at the end, preferably with the colors (here I used red for failed, and green for success). Is this possible at all? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Please note, there is probably better ways to lay out my script, as mentioned I'm not good with batch.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: One way to accomplish this would be to use something like this: set x=Hello    set x=%x% World!    echo %x%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(ab)use `set /p` to write without a linefeed:

```
@echo off
<nul set /p "=working...  "
timeout 3 >nul
echo done.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use -n for first command. It will not add newline for after echo.

*echo -n "Checking if the file is present..."*

Comment: `batch`'s `echo`doesn't have any switches.

Comment: Oh my bad. I didn't notice it. Thanks.